# Bash: Make the code dynamic by array using curl

Tags: arrays, bash, curl

**I am trying to implement following code dynamically:**

```
curl -k \ -w '\nHTTP STATUS: %{http_code}\n'\
-F "property_id[]=4ed9bc6f-f522-5363-a97a-772e9eeb65fc" \
-F "property_id[]=8219cd38-b5c9-4dc6-a119-c983cf1d844b" \
-F "property_id[]=60f1786c-602e-4379-b180-41b3ddca0361" \
-X 'POST' "https://availability.getaroom.com/api/1.1/room_availability?transaction_id=$$$$&check_in=07/27/2015&check_out=07/28/2015&rooms=1&adults=1&cancellation_rules=1&api_key=#####-33##-50###-&auth_token=$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"
```

Above curl runs successfully, but the problem for me is to make the above code dynamic. I have property_id[] in array.

I have got properties id in ${myArray[@]}  ==> (4ed9bc6f-f522-5363-a97a-772e9eeb65fc 8219cd38-b5c9-4dc6-a119-c983cf1d844b 60f1786c-602e-4379-b180-41b3ddca0361)

So here I implemented the code in this way by concatenating and merging it later in $RESPONSE:

```
for arg in "${myArray[@]}"; do
    REQUESTPROPERTY+="-F \"property_id[]=$arg\" \ ";
done 
REQUESTPROPERTY+="-X 'POST' \"$URL\""
TEST="curl -k \ -w '\nHTTP STATUS: %{http_code}\n'\ $REQUESTPROPERTY"
RESPONSE=`$TEST`
echo $RESPONSE
```

***But above code does not work for me.***

**Tried another method:**

```
curl -k \ -w '\nHTTP STATUS: %{http_code}\n'\
 for arg in "${myArray[@]}"; do
    -F "property_id[]=$arg" \
 done    
-X 'POST' "$URL"
```

But this also does not works for me.
Please help me out to find the correct solution for it. Thanks in advance